# Bootstrap Radio Buttons not toggling

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I'm currently trying to setup some bootstrap radio buttons. The code looks like the one from the Bootstrap examples, but the event is not fired to set a label active.
Here's my code:

```
<div id="mergeType" class="btn-group">
    <label for="radio1" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
        <input type="radio" name="mergeType" id="radio1" value="OVW">Überschreiben
    </label>
    <label for="radio2" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
        <input type="radio" name="mergeType" id="radio2" value="ADD">Hinzufügen
    </label>
    <label for="radio3" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
        <input type="radio" name="mergeType" id="radio3" value="KEE">Gefunde behalten
    </label>
    <label for="radio4" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
        <input type="radio" name="mergeType" id="radio4" value="DEL" checked="checked">Gefundene entfernen
    </label>
</div>
```

I don't do anything with the radio buttons in the JavaScript backend. What might be the issue here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not add jquery plugin:
Here is the working answer

https://jsfiddle.net/sesn/wLvzd193/2/

There is nothing wrong with your html

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-sm btn-success active">
    <input type="radio" name="mergeType" id="radio1" value="OVW">Überschreiben
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
    <input type="radio" name="mergeType" id="radio2" value="ADD" checked>Hinzufügen
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
    <input type="radio" name="mergeType" id="radio3" value="KEE">Gefunde behalten
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
    <input type="radio" name="mergeType" id="radio4" value="DEL">Gefundene entfernen
  </label>
</div>

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Radio 1 (preselected)
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio 3
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: According to the example on the official bootstrap homepage (http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/), the active state of the label should set automatically upon click, which is not working with my setup. I htink it is really a bootstrap specific problem and I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Oh sure, sorry forgot about that: https://jsfiddle.net/wLvzd193/1/ I added the Code of the bootstrap example as well. But even on that the toggle doesn't work.

Comment: Oh god, you are right. I simply forgot the jquery! Thanks!

Comment: I don't see the jquery that was added to make this example work, neither here nor in the jsfiddle example. In the jsfiddle example, I see that it is used but imports are not shown. Can you please include the specific import here and anything else needed to include jquery and make it work?

Answer (score 0):

There's some weird  problem about jsfiddle link to be present in the answer. Stack overflow's new stack snippet is preferred. But, I don't have time right now to figure out how to use stack snippet.

Sorry for the long intro. Just copy and paste your code in jsfiddle and run it. The code works just fine. I mean you wanted the radio buttons to toggle, right? So, there you go!

Please revert if you have any more queries.